# Badly registered generic type with Autofac

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, autofac

I have service

```
public class CircleProfileService : CircleService<ICircleProfileInput, ICircleProfileOutput, ICircleProfile>, ICircleProfileService
{
        public CircleProfileService(ICircleProfileQueryBuilder queryBuilder,
                                             ICircleQueryProcessor queryProcessor,
                                             ICircleParser<ICircleProfile> parser)
            : base(queryBuilder, queryProcessor, parser)
        {
        }
        ... other methods
}
```

As you can see I try to inject generic type of my parser.

```
public interface ICircleParser<out TOutput> where TOutput : ICircleParsedOutput
{
        IEnumerable<TOutput> Parse(string json);
}

public class CircleParser<TOutput> : ICircleParser<TOutput> where TOutput: ICircleParsedOutput, new() 
//new() is only one option to make project buildable as jsonParser want non-abstract type...
    {
        private readonly IJsonParser jsonParser;

        public CircleParser(IJsonParser jsonParser)
        {
            this.jsonParser = jsonParser;
        }

        public IEnumerable<TOutput> Parse(string json)
        {
            return jsonParser.Parse<TOutput>(json);
        }
    }
```

And here is how I register my generic types (everything like in Autofac documentation)

```
 builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(CircleParser<>)).As(typeof(ICircleParser<>));
```

But this always throws exception that cannot inject parser...

What am I doing wrong?

---

Error :

> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'MyProj.Services.DataServices.Circle.CircleProfileService' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
>   Cannot resolve parameter 'MyProj.Services.DataServices.Circle.Parsers.Interfaces.ICircleParser`1[MyProj.Services.DataServices.Circle.Outputs.Interfaces.ICircleProfile] parser' of constructor 'Void .ctor(MyProj.Services.DataServices.Circle.QueryBuilders.Interfaces.ICircleProfileQueryBuilder, MyProj.Services.DataServices.Circle.QueryProcessors.Interfaces.ICircleQueryProcessor, MyProj.Services.DataServices.Circle.Parsers.Interfaces.ICircleParser`1[MyProj.Services.DataServices.Circle.Outputs.Interfaces.ICircleProfile])'.

Comment: can you list the exception message in the question?

Comment: @MikeCorcoran, done

Comment: the error seems fairly clear. autofac can find no implementation of a class that implements `ICircleParser<ICircleProfile>`. you have registered the open generic `ICircleParser`, but you still need something that implements the resulting type you are asking for autofac to resolve for you.

Comment: @MikeCorcoran, If I understand you correctly I should add some empty `class CircleProfileParser : CircleParser<ICircleProfile>, ICircleParser<ICircleProfile>` ... ?

Comment: yes, autofac has two steps - registration and resolution. you have registered the open generic interface, now you must register things that actually implement it so when resolution happens, there is something concrete available for autofac to provide to your type it is constructing.

you would want just `class CircleProfileParser : CircleParser<ICircleProfile>` since `CircleParser<T>` implements `ICircleParser<T>`.

Comment: Another option, does your `ICircleProfile` implement `ICircleParsedOutput`? You have `TOutput:ICircleParsedOutput` constraint in `CircleParser<TOutput>` but it is unclear from your sample, whether `ICircleProfile` implements `ICircleParsedOutput`. If not, autofac would act as if nothing suitable registered upon resolving `CircleService`.

Comment: @Shorstok, yes `ICircleProfile ` implements `ICircleParsedOutput`

Comment: Then I vote for @MikeCorcoran answer. You can test it separately - try to resolve just `ICircleParser<ICircleProfile>` and see, you should get same error.

Comment: @MikeCorcoran, I've added `public class CircleProfileParser : CircleParser<CircleProfile>
    {
        public CircleProfileParser(IJsonParser jsonParser) : base(jsonParser)
        {
        }
    }` but this doesn't help... still same error... Or should I register it also?

Comment: The problem is you're having `ICircleProfile` as generic parameter in `ICircleParser<ICircleProfile> parser` dependency. Autofac doesnt know what to fit in `ICircleProfile`. You have options:

1. Register something that directly resolves from `ICircleParser<ICircleProfile>`, like: `container.Register<...>.As<ICircleParser<ICircleProfile>>()`

or 

2. Use concrete type in `CircleProfileService` dependency ctor, like

`public CircleProfileService(...,
                                             ICircleParser<*CircleProfileImpl*> parser)`

Comment: maybe create simple example in https://dotnetfiddle.net Then we can try to make it work

Comment: @Shorstok, yep, this helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unable to comment do to rep, so I am forced to make a post.

Do you have a binding for `IJsonParser`? If not, you need to add one so that autofac can inject an implementation of it into `CircleParser`